# Python Fibonacci sequence- while loop is not giving me the right result. I have tried changing the iterator but to no avail?

Tags: python, while-loop, iterator, logic, fibonacci

```
    num1 = 0
    num2 = 1
    find = 2
    fib_num = 0

    while find <= N:
        fib_num = num1 + num2
        num1 = num2
        num2 = fib_num
        find = find + 1
    print(find)


fibFind(7)
```

I have been having issues with the Fibonacci sequence- I have searched for the 7th number- the result should be 13. Where am I going wrong with the logic?

Thanks in advance for answer and explanation.

Comment: you forgot to define `N=7` and should print `fib_num`

Comment: A spin in the debugger will answer this question in five minutes or less.  You should say what result you got in addition to your expectation.  You should not require that people run your code to answer questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to print `fib_num`, not `find`.

```py
def fibFind(N):
    num1 = 0
    num2 = 1
    find = 2
    fib_num = 0

    while find <= N:
        fib_num = num1 + num2
        num1 = num2
        num2 = fib_num
        find = find + 1

    print(fib_num)


fibFind(7)
```

Better yet, return the fibonacci number from the function after the computation is done.

```py
def fibFind(N):
    num1 = 0
    num2 = 1
    find = 2
    fib_num = 0

    while find <= N:
        fib_num = num1 + num2
        num1 = num2
        num2 = fib_num
        find = find + 1

    return fib_num


print(fibFind(7))
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are searching for this.

```
def fibFind(N):
    num1 = 0
    num2 = 1
    find = 0
    fib_num = 0
    print("Fibonacci sequence:")
    while find <= N:
        print(num1)
        fib_num = num1 + num2
        num1 = num2
        num2 = fib_num
        find = find + 1
fibFind(7)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first two elements of the sequence could be done outside the loop :

```
# xn = xn−1 + xn−2
def fibFind(N):
num1 = 0
num2 = 1
find = 2
fib_num = 0
print(fib_num)
fib_num = fib_num + 1
print(fib_num)

while find <= N:
fib_num = num1 + num2
num1 = num2
num2 = fib_num
find = find + 1
print(fib_num)
fibFind(7)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing "find" which you used for iterating the loop from 2. You need to print the "fib_num", the variable that you are using to store the fibonacci number.

```
def fibFind(N) :
    num1 = 0
    num2 = 1
    find = 2
    fib_num = 0

    while find <= N:
        fib_num = num1 + num2
        num1 = num2
        num2 = fib_num
        find = find + 1
    print(fib_num)

fibFind(7)
```